# I am confused about new Promise((resolve, reject) => {[loop]}) is blocking while Promise.resolve().then([loop]) is not

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have three benchmark using builtin function of console.time(beforeBenchmark, benchmark and afterBenchmark).

Both of the code are quite identical. However, the difference lies in the construction of JS Promises API.

The first one contains a loop in the Promise resolve and the second one contains a loop in the Promise then.

I am not sure why the third console.log("after loop") takes significant longer time to complete which i designed this to be asynchronous. Thank you for your time to read this.

### Promise Resolve

before loop 
beforeBenchmark: 0.836ms 
after loop 
afterBenchmark: 40.987ms 
benchmark: 41.202ms

### Promise Then

before loop 
beforeBenchmark: 1.122ms 
after loop 
afterBenchmark: 2.872ms 
benchmark: 43.705ms

I have looked around Stack Overflow but I couldn't find any answer relating to this.

### First Type of Promise

```
console.time("beforeBenchmark");
console.time("benchmark");
console.time("afterBenchmark");
console.log("before loop");
console.timeEnd("beforeBenchmark");

let i = 0;

let promise = new Promise(( resolve, reject ) =>
{
    while (i < 10000000)
    {

        i++;
    }

    resolve();

}).then(() =>
{    
    console.timeEnd("benchmark")

});

console.log("after loop");
console.timeEnd("afterBenchmark");
```

### Result

```
before loop
beforeBenchmark: 0.836ms
after loop
afterBenchmark: 40.987ms
benchmark: 41.202ms
```

### Second Type of Promise

```
console.time("beforeBenchmark");
console.time("benchmark");
console.time("afterBenchmark");
console.log("before loop");
console.timeEnd("beforeBenchmark");
let i = 0;

let promise = Promise.resolve().then(() =>
{
    while (i < 10000000)
    {
        i++;
    }

    console.timeEnd("benchmark")
});


console.log("after loop");
console.timeEnd("afterBenchmark");
```

### Result

```
before loop
beforeBenchmark: 1.122ms
after loop
afterBenchmark: 2.872ms
benchmark: 43.705ms
```

Comment: they're both blocking ... at different times though ... but both definitely blocking ... try making the loop bigger in a browser ... both will trigger the "script is taking too long" message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Promise *constructor* runs synchronously. If you have blocking code inside `new Promise(...`, that code will run (and block) before the next line below the constructed Promise runs. This is why your first snippet has `afterBenchmark: 40.987ms`.

On the other hand, a `.then` callback will only run *once the current event loop has been cleared* (once all synchronous code has finished running) - it's like `setTimeout(fn, 0)` (not *exactly* the same, since `setTimeout` will run on the *next* iteration of the event loop, rather than at the end of the current loop, but it's quite similar). So, the `afterBenchmark` in your second code gets logged before the `then` has run, before the blocking loop has run.

Comment: Actually, immediately resolved Promises are ran from the same event loop, in a micro-task. So `const oups = ()=>Promise.resolve('too bad').then(oups); oups()` will block the thread, where a setTimeout wouldn't.